# Visual Studio sorting JSON properties wrong

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've run into a weird problem with Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise, version 15.5.2) that I can only replicate on one specific machine. The problem doesn't occur on other development machines.

Given a file `foo.resources.json` with the following contents:

```js
{
    "FooReparatur": "Reparatur",
    "FooVerlust": "Verlust",
    "FooWema": "Wema"
}
```

Applying the quick action `Sort Properties` results in the keys being in the wrong order:

```js
{
    "FooReparatur": "Reparatur",
    "FooWema": "Wema",
    "FooVerlust": "Verlust"
}
```

The configured language for Visual Studio is English, there is no schema selected for the given file. The configured language for Windows is Estonian, but the sorting order is wrong by that alphabet as well.

I checked for any funny unicode characters or anything similar via a hexdump, but found nothing of the like either. As mentioned before, the file sorts correctly on all other machines.

I've tried disabling all the (default) extensions the installation has, but that doesn't resolve the problem either.

I've looked through most of the settings for both general text editing and the specific file type, but I can't find a setting that could cause this. What could be the issue? How can I debug this further?

Comment: Can't find any option in VS 2017 Community Edition to sort properties. How are you triggering this?

Comment: @phuzi I'm using Enterprise, sorry, that was missing from the question before. The issue occurs when I use the quick actions menu to sort the properties, under `Alt + Enter`. The issue also occurs when I right-click the file and choose `Sort Properties`.

Comment: alt-enter, sounds like Resharper...

Comment: @jessehouwing No Resharper installed, but thanks for your input, I'll check if disabling all extensions affects the problem, even though none of them seem related. Update: Disabling all extensions doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: Clearly you have an installation problem on that particular machine. Are visual studio versions the same on both machines?

Comment: Has codeMaid extension "sort lines" the same wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a property of Estonian collation where 'V' and 'W' are treated as the same character. Hence, the next character that differs will be the significant one. As can be demonstrated by this C# code using .Net.

```
var words1 =  new[] { "FooR", "FooVer", "FooWem" };
var words2 = new[] { "FooR", "FooVa", "FooWb" };

var estonianCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("et-EE");
var estonianComparer = StringComparer.Create(estonianCultureInfo, false);

var sortedWords = words1.OrderBy(x => x, estonianComparer);
foreach (var word in sortedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}

Console.WriteLine("[-----]");

sortedWords = words2.OrderBy(x => x, estonianComparer);
foreach (var word in sortedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Output:

```
FooR
FooWem
FooVer
[-----]
FooR
FooVa
FooWb
```

Comment: Wow, that's unexpected and nonsensical, yet explains the bug perfectly. Nice find! I would've never thought of that, especially since the correct behavior would naturally be to handle the letters differently. I'll let your answer gather some attention so others can learn from it and then I'll hand you the bounty. Do you happen to know where the correct place would be to file this as a bug?

Comment: The solution, while a workaround until this gets resolved, was to change the region under the language settings to a different one (Control Panel → Language → Change date, time, or number formats → Formats). It's weird though, that Visual Studio prefers that setting over its own language settings.

Comment: Will probably require some careful reading of ISO14651 and/or UTS10 to figure out just why this is. From what I understand "W" is regarded as a foreign letter in Estonian and probably has some special handling according to the above documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin to sort  :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richie5um2.vscode-sort-json

If dosn't work, try to install again the visual studio and choose language English  to test if it work

Good Chance.